# How to "merge whole bunch of codes in WEBSTORM"

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, github, webstorm

I have to merge code between two files in Webstorm and I use Ctrl+D and shift each changes one by one, but instead "Is there any feature to shift all changes on a single click or at once ?"

There are about 800 differences to be merged in my package-lock.json. So I want any method/feature in webstorm to shift all changes on single click.

Comment: What do you mean by "merge code between two files" , do you want to merge file in version controlling system ( such as git ) ?

Comment: No, not in version controlling system. I just want to compare and merge 2 different files in webstorm.

Answer (score 0):

Just click the magic wand tool in the inbuilt resolution tool.

Answer (score 0):

Select all in the change content file `(ctrl + a )` and then right click on it and click `Accept` or click `Alt+Shift+Right`

[image]